# Angular 2(4) component with ControlValueAccessor testing

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular2-testing

I would like to test component which implements ControlValueAccessor interface for allow to use `[(ngModel)]` in my custom component, but the issue is that usual inputs comes correct but `ngModel` - `undefined`. Here is code example:

```js
@Component({
  template: `
    <custom-component
      [usualInput]="usualInput"
      [(ngModel)]="modelValue"
    ></custom-component>`
})

class TestHostComponent {
  usualInput: number = 1;
  modelValue: number = 2;
}

describe('Component test', () => {
  let component: TestHostComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestHostComponent>;
  let de: DebugElement;
  let customComponent: DebugElement;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        CustomComponent,
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
});
```

So, I expect usualInput Input() value in my customComponent will equal 1 (it is true), and ngModel value will equal 2, but ngModel = undefined and after debug I know that ControlValueAccessor writeValue method doesn't call in test environment (but it works correct for browser). So how can I fix it?

Comment: could you provide the source code of your `custom-component` ?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `ControlValueAccessor` component you do not have access to `ngModel` unless you injected it and did some tricks to avoid circular dependency.

`ControlValueAccessor` has `writeValue` method which receives values from control when it is updated — if you need, you can store this value in your component and then test it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap your test with async, and wait for `fixture.whenStable`

> ```
> it('should get ngModel', async(() => {  
>    let customComponent = debugEl.query(By.directive(CustomComponent)); 
>
>    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
>       fixture.detectChanges();
>       expect(customComponent.componentInstance.value).toEqual(2);        
>    }); 
> });
> ```